# how to align action items & title in action bar/ app bar?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, appbar

I'm a new android developer and I made lots of documentation till I got my own **action bar** with actions icon/**items**. but I want to know two things:

1. How to **align** the **title** at the **center** of action bar (lots of documentation showed it by using gravity attribute with new textView)?
2. How to **align** action **items** to the **left** of the action bar (as it is auto-positioned at the right side)?
   **TIP**: prefered to code in **XML**.

Here's my action bar

[image: action bar]

menu.XML

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/outline_search_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
    <item android:title="@string/action_bookmark"
        android:id="@+id/action_bookmark"
        android:icon="@drawable/outline_bookmark_border_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_help"
        android:title="@string/action_help"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_update"
        android:title="@string/action_update"
        app:showAsAction="never" />


</menu>
```

Comment: Add some of your code in order to help you

Comment: codes have been shown above @Mugiwara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Relative layout inside your **Toolbar** like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Your Title"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks that's better but is there any way to align items inside the toolbar instead of views

Comment: No, right now there is no method or attribute that can perform this kind of task.